# What countries may be entered without visa by the holder of a South Africa refugee travel document?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, south-africa, refugees

What countries in the world may be entered without visa by a refugee carrying a South Africa travel document such as the one illustrated?

[image]

Comment: Maybe related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143512/traveling-to-usa-using-the-south-african-refugee-travel-document/143583

Comment: A bit off-topic but I find it interesting that the cover is also translated in French as according to Wikipedia French is not an official language of South Africa, I'd rather have expected Afrikaans to be present on the cover. Any information regarding this ? Is that due to the fact the France at some point colonized some part of the country ?

Comment: @stbr French used to be the common lingua franca for diplomacy, international relations and in many international organizations until a few decades ago. It is a relatively new phenomenon that English has taken over this role. Many countries still use French text in their travel documents, not only for refugees, but also in regular passports.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo my UK passport, and my wife's US passport, have English/French field descriptors for all the data on the personal ID page, doubtless for the reasons you state.  (The US passport has Spanish language descriptors also, probably for local reasons.)

Comment: I think a lot of countries will allow you to travel visa free as South Africa has agreed to 28 July 1951 united nations refugee convention treaty. I would get it in writing though from Consulate of country you’re wanting to visit as some airlines don’t let you board. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Visa free countries are:

- The country where you fled persecution
- Country of Origin

> Recognized refugees, can apply for and use the refugee passport from the Department of Home Affairs for travel abroad. This South African-issued refugee passport is valid for travel abroad, including to the country of origin.
>
> Canada: Immigration and Refugee Board of Canada, South Africa: Whether the travel document issued to refugees is valid for travel to the country from which the person fled persecution, including the Democratic Republic of the Congo

([Refworld](https://www.refworld.org/docid/579771b64.html))

Furthermore, it goes on to state that returning to your country of origin on this travel document could result in its revocation:

> returning to their country of origin indicates... that the refugee no longer fears persecution... it is likely that [they] will lose refugee status. If the refugee status is revoked, the refugee passport is also revoked

Comment: You've misinterpreted your source. The DRC is only given as an example of a 'country from which [you] fled persecution', and not as a country which grants visa-free entry to all holders of that travel document. So only refugees from the DRC could use it to return home without a visa.

Comment: Furthermore, it goes on to state that returning to your country of origin on this travel document could result in its revocation: "returning to their country of origin indicates... that the refugee no longer fears persecution... it is likely that [they] will lose refugee status... If the refugee status is revoked, the refugee passport is also revoked."

Comment: The answer is incorrect; as @knowah observes, the answer's assertions are not supported by the cited source. Downvoted.

Comment: @David edited post

Comment: The assertion about DRC is still unsupported, sorry.

Comment: @David what do you mean?

Comment: @David edited post

Comment: The partial sentence you quote in the second sentence of the first quote does not support the idea that the holder of a refugee travel document issued by South Africa will necessarily be admitted to the DRC (or to any other state). The sentence does support the idea that it's OK with South Africa to travel internationally with the refugee travel doc (keeping in mind that travel to country or origin or persecution may lead to termination of asylee status), but South Africa does not and cannot assert that country X will take the doc, nor that country Y will not. Each state decides on its own.